# Database creation is failing, Why?

Tags: c#, sql-server

One of the application is creating a database for that we are passing domain user and password. For some user I am getting the below error, what this mean and how to solve it?

I tried to give `sysadmin` permission to user `domain\userA`, but even same error.

Is this something related to domain user permission, etc?

**Note -** When I query `EXECUTE AS LOGIN='domain\userA'` I am also getting the same error `Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\userA', error code 0x37`.

```
 [Error] [2/3/2020 3:35:57 PM]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\userA', error code 0x37. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\userA', error code 0x37.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.ServerManagementStoreDataContext.CreateServerOperatorLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.ManagementDbContext.CreateServerOperatorLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SecurityHelper.CreateServerOperatorRole(String accountName, String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBFarmBase.InstallManagementDB(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBFarmBase.ProcessRecordImplementation()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`3 updateProgress)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.CreateSBFarm(FarmCreationModel model)
```

Comment: Seems like the environment doesn't have access to the AD? Can you login through SSMS with the same credentials?

Comment: I tried to give `sysadmin` permission to user `domain\userA`, but even same error.

Is this something related to domain user permission, etc?

Comment: @404, I tried with other domain user `domain\userB` and it's working. Something wrong with user `domain\userA`, but what?

Comment: @404, with SSMS, I am always login through windows authentication with user `domain\userA` default. I can't change to SQL auth or change in user for windows auth

Comment: When I query `EXECUTE AS LOGIN='domain\userA'; I am also getting the same error 'Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\userA', error code 0x37.`

Comment: i would suggest comparing the `server roles`, `user mapping`, and `securables` tabs of the properties for both userA and userB

Comment: @user584018 post your code and what you're doing. That error says nothing about creating a database. It says it's a `Microsoft.ServiceBus` wizard that tries to `CreateServerOperatorLogin` and fails because it `Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\userA'`. What are you executing and how? Perhaps the account you use isn't a domain account? Or you're deploying in one domain and tried to add operator accounts from *another* domain?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I am trying to do service bus configuration. In SSMS when I am trying to query `EXECUTE AS LOGIN='domain\userA'` , I am also seeing the same error

Comment: You'd get that if you tried to use an account from an untrusted domain domain, if the server machine isn't part of the domain, or if the SQL Server service is a local account (eg Local System or Local Service) and so can't look up accounts from the domain.